# deleting the file after uploading file in html

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have an file upload input, by iterating it I am storing it into table dynamically. some time 3 times, some times 8 times. The following code is being used in the table.

```
  <input
    type="file"
    alt=""
    id="document Type Name"
    accept="image/types"
    class="upload"
    name="file Upload"
    onchange="uploadFile(this,'${entry.documentId}')"
  />
```

The problem is , the table's 1st column have the file name with document name, if you click the document name it will open up a window to upload the document. process same...
in 2nd column the document name is coming, 3rd column having the delete button,

Problem is how to delete the uploaded file from the browser or uploaded row?

Comment: The very secret answer is... PHP...

Comment: To clarify, you're asking how to delete the file from the server after it's been read into the database? That is going to depend on which server side technology you are using (PHP, ASP.NET, Java, etc)

Comment: You could get more help if you specify the server side language you're working with (as nothed by @ElGavilan).

Comment: (i am not asking about server side deletion,client side only)it happens before going to server call, the total uploaded documents are in browser only,